# Mode of convergence & DCT

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, pointwise-convergence

Let {${g_n}$} be a sequence of measurable functions defined on $[a,b]$.Suppose $|g_n(x)|\leq K$ for a.e $x$, where $K< \infty $. Suppose further $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{a}^{c} g_n(x)dx=0$ for all $a \leq c\leq b$.

Prove that for any $f \in \mathbb{L^1{[a,b]}}$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{a}^{b} f(x)g_n(x)dx=0$.

My thoughts:The idea is to use DCT for $f_n=fg_n$ on $[a,b]$. Since $g_n$ is int'ble and $f \in \mathbb{L^1} ,f_n \in \mathbb{L^1}$. Moreover, $|f_n| \leq K|f|$ a.e on $[a,b]$. If I can prove that $f_n$ converges to $0$ pointwise a.e, I'm done. But, that's what I'm struggling to cope with. I know I have to use some mode of convergence but not sure which one is it.

Is my argument up to this point correct?. Can we argue that $g_n$ converges to $0$ in $\mathbb{L^1}$?.Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: I hope everything is clear now. Previously, I forgot all important 'limit' part.

Comment: What do you mean with for all $x \in [a,c]$?

Comment: Is the limit of the integrals of $g_n$ from a to b and not a to c?

Comment: I meant, I need to make the argument that $f_n$  converges to 0 pointwise a.e.To do that, I need to know the convergence of $g_n$, which is what I have difficulty understanding.

Comment: it is not the case that $f_n \to 0$..you have that only the integrals of $g_n$ go to zero..not $g_n$..

Comment: It is form $a$ to $c$. I should've mentioned $a \leq b \leq c$. Will edit it. Sorry for that.

Comment: Again my counterexample applies for $a=0$ and $b=c=1$

Comment: I hate to say that but it should precisely be $a≤c≤b$. I've been so careless typing this.

Comment: Again for $c=b=1$ and a=0 my countexample aplies..what do you mean?

Comment: Please check if the question makes sense now.

Comment: It is the same..you cannot always have the $f_n \to 0$...i gave you a counterxample

Comment: Yeah got it.That's what I was wondering if I could do it or not. Guess I've to think of a different approach. Since the measure space is finite, I may have to think about theorems related to that.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true.

Take $g_n(x)=\cos{(2\pi n x)}$ and $f(x)=e^x$ on $[0,1]$ where $c=b=1$

Comment: Sorry there was a typo.The limit part was missing. I edited the question.